# How to limit the total cart/order weight?

Tags: cart, orders, magento-2.1

Magento 2.1.

How can I limit the total cart/order weight so it does not exceed 7 KG?

I use "Table Rates" shipping method

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Cart model in magento 2.1 (`/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/Cart.php`)

We can see that the `Save()` method dispatches 2 events, `checkout_cart_save_before` and `checkout_cart_save_after`.

I would recommend that you create a plugin for `checkout_cart_save_before` where you would check the total weight of the quote, if it exceeds your maximum throw a magento `ValidatorException` with a message to the customer, otherwise proceed to save method.

Comment: Better use `sales_quote_save_before`. Supports APIs